# Convert Dynamic URLs with query parameters to static URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For dynamic content on my website, I use urls with query variables

```
e.g. http://www.example.com/directory/?state=NJ&city=Wayne&zip=07474 or
     http://www.example.com/directory/index.php?state=NJ&city=Wayne&zip=07474
```

I would like to convert them to seo-friendly static urls instead

```
e.g. http://www.example.com/directory/Wayne-NJ-07474/
```

I researched on SO and found it seems like a htaccess rewrite rule is the way to go.

I am a noob when it comes to htaccess constructs and what I fail to understand is will I still get the data associated with the individual query parameters i.e. state, city, and zip. Meaning will I still be able to access them via _REQUEST()?

I would also appreciate if someone would help me with the rewrite rule for my specific case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+directory/(?:index\.php)\?state=([^\s&]+)&city=([^\s&]+)&zip=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /directory/%2-%1-%3? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^directory/([^-/]+)-([^-/]+)-([^-/]+)/?$ directory/?state=$2&city=$1&zip=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. I will try this out later today (and accept the answer if it works). Can you please explain why there is a 302 redirect? If these dynamic links are new (i.e. havent been indexed by Search Engines) will I still need the 302?

Comment: 302 is good for testing otherwise 301 is permanently cached by browsers.

Comment: So after testing the final solution should have a 301 redirect, correct?

Comment: Yes definitely use 301 after verifying the rules.

Comment: This works great @anubhava. Thanks for  your help! The only issue is that if I navigate to http://www.example.com/directory/, I get a 404. This will affect "breadcrumbs". Is there a way to address this? Maybe redirect to another location?

Comment: Try adding `DirectoryIndex index.php` at top of you .htaccess for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87389/discussion-between-rogerb-and-anubhava).